# Responsive item grid

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design

I am working on an app that uses AngularJS. My app has an array of JSON objects. Each of these objects has a picture (thumbnail), name, and description. I want to display each of these objects as a "tile" in my UI. The tile would consist of a blue rectangle. Inside the rectangle would be the thumbnail. To the right would be the title and the description. Something like the following:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| +---------+  [Title Goes Here]                  |
| | Picture |  [Description goes here. It may     |
| |         |   wrap around to multiple lines.    |
| +---------+   Still, this is the idea.]         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to lay these tiles out in a grid. However, I'm trying to also do this responsively. I'm thinking I'm trying to do something I can't do. Basically, I want each tile to take up 25% of the available width. If the screen goes below a certain threshold, I would like each tile to take 33% then 50% and finally, if one a phone, 100%.

I saw [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It looks nice. However, it didn't seem to have any responsive abilities.  I then saw [FreeWall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/). This has some responsiveness. However, I didn't see AngularJS support. Does anyone know how to do what I'm trying? I have the HTML for each "tile". But creating a responsive grid that animates when someone sorts / filters is throwing me off. The animation piece is why I want to use something like Masonry or FreeWall. Yet, I still need the responsiveness.

Thanks!

Comment: Masonry is indeed responsive.

Comment: how do you use Masonry responsively? I do not see it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "responsive". If you look at the Masonry home page that you linked to, it's very responsive. As you widen/narrow the browser, the divs expand and contract, and ultimately resort when they hit certain breakpoints. Those divs have % widths.